# Error with API Google

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have this error

> Fatal error: Cannot call constructor in
>   C:\wamp\www\google-login-api\src\Google\Service\Analytics.php on line
>   84

In this line

```
 $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($gClient); echo
 $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:111111',
       '7daysAgo',
       'today',
       'ga:sessions');
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't do echo do var_dump to find out what it is.

Comment: Also what version of the Google Analytics Client library  are you on? `git checkout -b v1-master ...`